# Jquery não executa no primeiro carregamento da página!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá,

Tenho uma página onde o primeiro carregamento dela o Jquery não é executado, ao realizar atualização da página (refresh, F5) a função escrita em JQuery passa a funcionar.

Estou utilizando JQuery com a tecnologia **Ruby On Rails**.

**Soluções:**

- Adicionar script no final do HTML.
- Remoção do Turbolinks do application.html.erb
- Adicionar a função no application.js

**OBS: Porém nenhuma das soluções citadas funcionaram.**

Parte da função JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    request_guides();
});


function request_guides() {
    //logica
}
```

Também foi feita dessa forma

```
$(function() {
    request_guides();
});


function request_guides() {
    //logica
}
```

Alguém tem ideia de uma solução ?

Grato!

Comment: Isso parece mais erro do navegador ao carregar o jQuery. A conexão tá lenta? O que as ferramentas do navegador dizem com relação à carga do jQuery? Como você o carrega na página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer com javascript puro, veja o que acontece:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    request_guides();
}, false);
```

Se não der certo, me informe para remover a resposta.

Comment: A forma foi exatamente essa, porém como estou utilizando o Rails o turbolinks estava interferindo e então apliquei essa solução adaptando para JQuery:

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
       //logica
});

Answer (score 1):

Solução aplicada com base na resposta descrita nesse tópico, aplicando as devidas alterações para utilização com Ruby On Rails, sem a necessidade de adicionar os scripts no final do body.

**Solução adaptada para JQuery:**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    //Logica
});
```